# jquery .post ajax function not working in IE + FF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a site for my sports team. It's displaying the next training and match dates from data in a a MySQL database through PHP.
I want to let the user add their presence on these appointments and update the div with confirmed users through AJAX.

I call the next function for it :

```
function swapContent(div, status, soort, itemid, userid) {
$("#"+div).html('<p>loading ...</p>').show();
    var url = "training.php";
    $.post(url, {status: status, soort: soort, itemid: itemid, userid: userid} ,function(data) {
    $("#"+div).html(data).show();
    });
}
```

The problem is that it's working like a charm in Chrome, but not on FF and IE, both latest versions...

Any tips?

Comment: Are there any errors? If you add a error handler to your ajax call does it give you anything?

Comment: Can you post your call to `swapContent`?  It would be nice to see what data you are passing to the function.

Comment: the call : <a href="#" style="float:left" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:updatediv('training','Aanwezig',<? echo "'$soort','$itemid','$userid'";?>);">Aanwezig</a>

Comment: $soort = 'training' or 'match' / status = 'present' or 'absent' / $itemid + $userid are just integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that they are having issues with the naming you used, ie:

```
status: status
```

try changing the argument names for the function and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it solved. As you can see I'm passing the var $userid with the .post. The problem was that in IE and FF I wasn't logged in, so the $userid was empty and the php-page couldn't run so no output. When I logged in, everything works fine ...

```
/me feels stupid
```

Thx for the help anyway !